# How to build bootstrap panel-footer using 3 equally-spaced buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a panel footer building from 3 radio buttons.

It looks like this now:

[my panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TdHV.png)

I want the buttons to stretch and fill the footer.

this is my code:

```
 <div class="panel-heading">
                        <strong>Title</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="media">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" style="width:30%"> Option 1
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" style="width:30%"> Option 2
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" style="width:30%"> Option 3
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

any ideas? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, try including grid in your code.

Add class="class="col-sm-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4" in the button tag and make width="100%" for all the three buttons.

For more reference about grid:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Use `btn-group-justified`.

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group-justified btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
```